# Using swift am trying to get the index value of a particular label in an array of a phone number labels

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I am attempting to get the index value of an array of CNLabelValue phone labels.
I could iterate over them and get it that way but I know the .idex method would work just can't figure the syntax after of:

```
let labelIndex = mutableContact.phoneNumbers.index(of: <#T##CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>#>)
```

Comment: hey could you be a little more clear about what you wanna ask/ do ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this:-

```
let arr = ["a","b","c"]
if let index = arr.index(where: { (item) -> Bool in
  return (item == "c") 
}) {
    print(index)
}
```

> Output: 2

Comment: Thanks I however tried this with CNLabeledValue array and get an error:
PhoneLabelsTableViewController.swift:281:18: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>' and 'String'
So it comes down to a type issue

Comment: You need to conform equatable protocol for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
let idx = mutableContact.phoneNumbers.index(where: { (model) -> Bool in

        return if model == YOUR_OBJ

})
```

here,

> **(model)** is of type CNPhoneNumber

and in the if check you should put the check for which you want to get the index.

> **(model)** should be compared with your own obj for which you want to
>   filter.

Comment: Thanks - will try this - I have used iterating and that worked but it is the long way round.

Comment: Cool lemme know in case you need help. Try to avoid iteration though.

Comment: I am trying the code now however I don't understand what  the (model) would be.
I think the following might be the right approach I just don't understand the syntax:

let idx = mutableContact.phoneNumbers.index(of: CNLabeledValue, "iPhone") 
Gives the following error:
.... PhoneLabelsTableViewController.swift:280:42: Argument labels '(of:, _:)' do not match any available overloads.

Comment: model is already of the type that you are using, i.e. phoneNumbers, just put any name like model or obj to refer the index while the index(of:) function iterates through your collection

Comment: http://www.kaleidosblog.com/swift-data-structure-how-to-create-sort-filter-array-of-objects-in-swift

 should help.

Comment: Thanks for the help - can't get it quite right with either Umar or Hussain's answers so as a work-around I have used iteration - see my answer. Works fine but not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var labelIndex = 0

for (i,bod) in mutableContact.phoneNumbers.enumerated() {
    print(i,bod.label!)
    if bod.label == labelP {labelIndex = i; break}      
}

mutableContact.phoneNumbers.remove(at: labelIndex)
```

A routine to iterate over all the CNLabelValues for .phonenumbers and then test if they match labelP (function parameter) and return the index (labelIndex = i) of a matched item.

then mutableContact.phoneNumbers.remove(at: labelIndex)`

Comment: Please add info about your answer

Comment: You better explain your solution instead of simply posting some code. Maybe it's worth reading [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).